# Check equality of isomorphic graphs with various vertex labels in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphism

I know to check the equality of 2 graphs regardless of the vertex labels, one can use the `is_isomorphic()` function in NetworkX. However, I have a set of graphs that has fixed number of nodes, edges and connectivity, that is, are all isomorphic to each other, but the labels of the vertices keep changing. In this case, how can I check equality of graphs where all vertex labels also need to be identical?

Each graph looks like below. Each vertex is labeled by a long string.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [`is_isomorphic`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic) you can use for this the `node_match` parameter. It also has two already implemented methods to compare equality based on node attributes: [`numerical_node_match`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.numerical_node_match.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.numerical_node_match) and [`categorical_node_match`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.categorical_node_match.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.categorical_node_match). In both cases you need to supply the name of the node attribute(s) and the default value(s).

If you directly want to use the node label, i.e. the node id, e.g. `020000010000 in G == True`. Then you can either use [`convert_node_labels_to_integers`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers) with `label_attribute="label"` and afterwards use `categorical_node_match("label", None)` or create your own `node_match` function.

Comment: I checked ```categorical_node_match```. I guess the node attribute I need to compare is the node's label itself, but I cannot understand what does the default value mean. I have updated my question with a graph. Can you give me an idea what should I set as default?

Comment: I've extended my answer. Please take a look.